# For a custom trie that uses the state trie methods and functionality, can triestate.Set be skipped?

Tags: go-ethereum, database

The `Update` method in the `Database` class in `trie` package, takes a parameter `*triestate.Set`. Is it possible to skip this variable, and simply pass `&triestate.Set{}` to it? I am using `Update` method for my own custom trie, in a consensus engine ([link](https://github.com/resilience-me/panarchy-engine/)) I have built in the past month. It also uses `state.Database().OpenTrie` and then `trie` methods `GetStorage` and `UpdateStorage`. I've tested with just an empty `Set` and it seems to work. I know how to generate one with `New`, but `Set` is designed for the state trie, with both an accounts map and a storage map, and my trie is just storing one value per account for an arbitrary number of accounts. Is `Set` required, or is it more for optimizing how database back end does its job, but it will be able to do it even without `Set`?

```
func (db *Database) Update(root common.Hash, parent common.Hash, block uint64, nodes *trienode.MergedNodeSet, states *triestate.Set) error {
    if db.config != nil && db.config.OnCommit != nil {
        db.config.OnCommit(states)
    }
    if db.preimages != nil {
        db.preimages.commit(false)
    }
    return db.backend.Update(root, parent, block, nodes, states)
}
```